# Vector norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Is it true that for vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R^n$ $|\Vert x\Vert -\Vert y\Vert| \ge \Vert x-y\Vert $?

Can I simply use the triangle inequality $\Vert x\Vert +\Vert y\Vert \ge \Vert x+y\Vert $ to prove it even though there is a minus sign between the norms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: The expression should be- $|\Vert x\Vert -\Vert y\Vert| \ge \Vert x-y\Vert$. No need of extra$|.|$.

Comment: Let assume $n=1, \ x=2, \ y=-3$. Then, this inequality does not hold. I think the inequality sign will be opposite.

Comment: "Can I simply use the triangle inequality..." Yes, you have to use the triangle inequality, but in a slightly more involved way. Note that $\|x-y\|\le \|x\| - \|y\|$ is false.

Answer (score 5):

No, simply consider two vectors $x \ne y$ that have the same norm.

However, the inequality $| \| x\| - \|y\|| \le \|x - y\|$ holds [it is often called reverse triangle inequality]. By the triangle inequality, the following inequalities hold:
$$ \| x \| = \|x - y + y\| \le \| x - y \| + \|y\|$$
$$ \| y \| = \|y - x + x\| \le \| y - x \| + \|x\|$$

The statement now follows from observing that $|a| \le b$ is equivalent to "$a \le b$ and $-a \le b$".